# Standard basis of a Matrix with identical entries.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

How would you represent a $\mathbb{R}$-Matrixspace which looks like this

$$\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix}$$

with standard basis

I can't think of anything else but

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \quad \mbox{and} \quad 
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

but can we then call that a standard basis, because not all entries except one of them 
is 0?

Comment: "R-vector space"? What you wrote there looks like a $\;2\times 2\;$ matrix

Comment: but it still carries the structure of a vector space.

Comment: No, it doesn't. What is true is that **the set** of all $\;2\times2\;$ matrices, say over the real field, can be made easily into a vector space. Is that what you meant? And if you did, then what *exactly* is your question, anyway?

Comment: okay I am going to call it a matrix-space if that makes you happier, you can see vectors as matrices with only one column, so there is no real difference between the two. SO  I am calling matrix spaces and vectorspaces both as vectorspaces, so does the book I am reading

Comment: I'm not sure *any* vector space has one, single "standard basis", but I guess the vector space of $\;2\times 2\;$ real matrices has a rather "standard basis" as follows: $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\,,\;\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\,,\;\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\,,\;\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Mcs did you intend your matrices above to be $2 \times 2$? They are currently $2 \times 1$ (displayed as single columns).

Comment: okay I am sorry did not make myself clear enough, you said in your comment that the set of all 2*2 matrices can easily be made into a vector space, what I am asking is, let's say we have the set of all 2*2 matrices over R, all of which look like this $\binom{ab}{ba}$ how would you describe that vector space, with standard basis?

Comment: Only after seeing the answer below I finally understand, *perhaps*, what you meant: you want, apparently, the vector space of all symmetric matrices with the same element on the main diagonal! Ok, read that answer.

Comment: the span of $$ \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\,,\;\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\,,‌​\;\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\,,\;\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} $$ would contain also the matrices which have all different elements, when I said it carries the structure of a vector space, I mean its elements are matrices but it obeys all the rules a vector space obeys, in any case I am gonna go with the below answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$W = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & a \end{bmatrix} \;\Big|\; a,b \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$

is indeed a subspace of $M_2(\mathbb{R})=\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ the space of all $2 \times 2$ real matrices.

While $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ has a "standard basis" of matrices... 
$$E_{11} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
E_{12} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
E_{21} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad \mbox{and} \quad
E_{22} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
...if you pick some random subspace (like your $W$) there is no general notion of a "standard basis".

Your proposal of $E_{11}+E_{22}=I_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and
$E_{12}+E_{21}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is a nice choice of basis. It's as "standard" as you can hope for -- but wouldn't really necessarily be called that.

In general, some vector spaces have a basis which is accepted as "the standard basis" but not all vector spaces have such a thing. Even in such a case, the way the basis is ordered (which effects coordinate vectors) isn't standardized.

For example: $\mathbb{R}^3$ has the standard basis ${\bf i}={\bf e}_1=(1,0,0)$, ${\bf j}={\bf e}_2=(0,1,0)$, and ${\bf k}={\bf e}_3=(0,0,1)$. In fact, the order ${\bf i}$ then ${\bf j}$ then ${\bf k}$ is the standard order.

On the other hand, $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ has the standard basis of $E_{ij}$'s as mentioned above. But there is no universally accepted "standard" ordering for this basis.

Another common vector space with a standard basis is the algebra polynomials: $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Here the standard basis  is $\{1,x,x^2,\dots\}$.

But take some vector space like $W = \{ (a,b,c) \;|\; a+2b+3c=0 \}$ (a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$) and while $W$ has a basis (in fact infinitely many bases) it doesn't have a "standard basis".

Comment: thanks I understand fully what you mean, the problem is, I am studying in German, and the question is asking the standard basis of a Matrix which has identical elements, like a, b or c on certain positions, and I can either say there is no standard basis or give basically the answer I am giving, with several 1's in one basis element

Comment: The word 'standard' is defined by the community of people who are studying these objects - even though $I_{1}$ and $I_{2}$ would be a reasonable choice for a 'standard' I can't see why they would have to be the only ones. Depending on which inner product you were using for $M_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ you could lay out a convincing argument for $B_{1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}I_{1}$ and $B_{2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}I_{2}.$ Your textbook/course organiser should make it clear what 'standard' means in your context, or else you cannot give a proper answer.